# How to fill a new repository with a working copy

Tags: svn, repository, working-copy

I have a working copy checked out and a new empty repository. How can I fill that new repository using the working copy?

I don't have access to the original SVN.

I could delete all `.svn` dirs and do `svn commit`, but I'm wondering about some smarter way.

Thanks for tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a copy of the repository WITHOUT the ".svn" files, you can do `svn export`. This will give you a clean copy of the code. Then you simply need to do an `svn import` or an `svn add` to get those files into your new repository. Of course, all version history will be lost, but that's what happens when you create a new repository!

Comment: He can't do "svn export" -- because he doesn't have access to the original SVN (repository). Does anyone know what SVN does if you DON'T delete .svn files/dirs and do an "svn commit" of some OTHER repo's working copy to a brand-new repo?  My guess: SVN would be confused -- despite @sarnold 's answer that these files/dirs might be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't delete those .svn directories until I had gathered all the svn properties out of them; if you don't maintain the `svn:keywords` properties, you might be surprised when your `$Id: $` or `$Revision: $` or similar tags go missing, or you rely on the crlf-automatic munging to work between Windows and Unix machines.

Answer (score 0):

If there's a change to your server location, `svn switch` is your friend. Also, `svn import` can help you to import unversioned files to a new repository.

However, if you want to IMPORT to a clean repository with all Subversion metadata and history, you will need to create a dump of your first repository (as an administrator, which unfortunately you mentioned, you do not have access) and `svnadmin load` it.